# Execute a Cronjob Every Minute Between Two Times

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

I need to run a bash script in crontab every minute between **8:45am** and **9:50am** of every day.

**Code**:

```
45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59 8 * * * /home/pull.sh > /home/logs/pull.log 2>&1
00/50 9 * * * /home/pull.sh > home/logs/pull.log 2>&1
```

Is this correct and/or the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: as  you have tagged this w both `linux` and `unix`, I'd mention that older `unix` systems didn't support range times as given in the answers below. In any case the only efficiency gain is fewer characters in a crontab entry. An infinitesimal gain ;-/ Better to look at other issues. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
45-59/1 8 * * * /home/pull.sh > /home/pull.log 2>&1
00-50/1 9 * * * /home/pull.sh > /home/pull.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

According to that website, you can do something like this:

```
45-59 8 * * * /home/pull.sh > /home/logs/pull.log 2>&1
```

I'm not certain what you're looking to do with this line:

```
00/50 9 * * * /home/pull.sh > home/logs/pull.log 2>&1
```

I actually don't know what that will do.